# ASP.Net using iTextSharp Create PDF Document error at HTMLWorker.ParseToList

Tags: asp.net, pdf-generation, itext

I am trying to generate a PDF using HTML template.

i am having trouble in parsing the html generated.
here is my code

```
 using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Documents/EmailTemplates/test.pdf"), FileMode.Create))
        {
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fs);
            using (StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(contents))
            {
                List<iTextSharp.text.IElement> parsedList = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(stringReader, null);
                document.Open();
                foreach (object item in parsedList)
                {
                    document.Add((IElement)item);
                }
                document.Close();
            }
        }
```

i get error at **HTMLWorker.ParseToList(stringReader, null);**
shows null reference, but stringReader has content needed

Comment: Where is styles being declared?

Comment: its part in html template. i see some examples where they gave null fro styles and it is executed perfectly.

Comment: What version of iTextSharp are you using? In your posted code sample you have `HTMLWorker.ParseToList(stringReader, styles)` but in your error message you have `HTMLWorker.ParseToList(stringReader, null)`. Which one is your actual code? Also, if you post a stack trace we might be able to help you more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the iTextSharp version HTMLWorker.ParseToList() doesnt work properly in latest version, if you are using the latest version, delete it and add new reference to v1.x that will fix your problem